# How to redirect another sub domain via ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a sub domain like `dashboard.domain.com`, I need redirect to `dashboard.domain.com` when I invoke an action in the controller.

I wrote the code in ASP.NET Core 3.1

```
public IActionResult SimulationDashboard()
{
    _indexpage = "dashboard.domain.com";

    HttpWebRequest reqDashboard = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_indexpage);
    reqDashboard.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  
    reqDashboard.CookieContainer.SetCookies(reqDashboard.RequestUri, _dashboardToken);
    reqDashboard.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("jweToken", "xxxyyy"));
    reqDashboard.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("authMode", "token"));

    return Redirect(_indexpage);
}
```

I got an error, I hope to bring cookies parameters when redirect another domain name (eg: `abc.domain.com`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are one suggestion for you. You shouldn't use `HttpWebRequest` in asp.net core, it will cause performance issue.

And you want `bring cookies parameters when redirect another domain name`. You can check the test result, and if it useful to you, you can refer my below code.

#### Test Result

[image]

#### Test Code

*Tips: you should configure the cookie_name settings in your every subdomain site.*

This is very important, if you don't have this, it will not work.

**1. ConfigureServices method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // create the cookie_name you want share between two subdomain site
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".TestName";
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        // you domain '.domain.com'
        options.Cookie.Domain = ".jasonp2.website";
    });
    // you should use HttpClient, not HttpWebRequest 
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

**2. Add `app.UseCookiePolicy();` in  `Configure` method**

[image]

**3. In Controller.**

[image]

```
public IActionResult SimulationDashboard()
{
    CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions
    {
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
        Secure = true,
        Domain = ".jasonp2.website"
    };
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        ".TestName",
        DateTime.Now.ToString() + "COOKIE_VALUE",
        option);
    string _indexpage = "https://www.jasonp2.website";
    return Redirect(_indexpage);
}
```

Comment: i have the same problem,could you share the complete code of your controller.The current code seems incomplete. thank you.

Comment: @denli8 This is the complete Controller code, the previous code to define HomeController is in the picture.

Comment: But it seems that _httpclient is not used in HomeController

Comment: @denli8 Yes,this answer is for `winter`, he use httpwebrequest in .net core. For you, you can remove it.